# How to use POSIX in find and replace with regexp in Sublime Text 2

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext2, posix

I am trying to build a regexp in ST2 for all spaces preceeded by a digit and followed by a character. My text contains Unicode symbols (Cyrillic letters). So:

```
(?<=\d) (?=\w)
```

only works with ASCII letters. I tried to modify my expression to use `[[:alpha:]]`. But this:

```
(?<=\d) (?=[[:alpha:]])
```

does not work. Does ST2 support POSIX symbol classes?

Comment: Have you tried to add the flag 'u' (for unicode)?

Comment: Could you show me the exact way to do that?

Comment: It depends on you regex engine: have a look at: http://regex101.com/r/zJ3eE2  if you remove the tag 'u' you get the problem you described. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with ST2. You might have an overload for that: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=10778

Comment: Alex Popov, you found the answer to the question? Whether it is possible to use POSIX in Sublime Text? Thanks.